# How to install devstack on Ubuntu 14.04 single node desktop environment

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install devstack on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop computer.
Everything goes fine, except the "./stack.sh" command returns the following error :

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
    libkrb5-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev (= 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
    libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
    libyaml-dev : Depends: libyaml-0-2 (= 0.1.4-3ubuntu3) but 0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
    openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1)
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
    + exit_trap
    + local r=100
    ++ jobs -p
    + jobs=
    + [[ -n '' ]]
    + kill_spinner
    + '[' '!' -z '' ']'
    + [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
    + echo 'Error on exit'
    Error on exit
    + [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
    +         /home/pulkit/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
    World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-08-11-082706.txt for details
    + exit 100
```

Comment: Please report this kind of questions on http://serverfault.com/ that is more suited

Answer (score 0):

As I have reputation problem, so I can not comment your question . Anyway have you done an `sudo apt-get update`?